# Loading dataTable values into DOM id fields

Tags: javascript

In my admin area I have over 50 modules that are used by volunteers to maintain database tables. In each module I have a form for editing records and a dataTable for listing all the records. To edit a record the user finds the record in the dataTable and selects/clicks the row. The click activates a table click event when then causes the record information to populate the form as illustrated in the following code.

```
    let rowData = oTable.row(this).data();
    $('#bio_name').val(rowData.bio_name);
    $('#bio_title').val(rowData.bio_title);
    $('#bio_sub_fk').val(rowData.bio_sub_fk);
    $('#bio_text_top').val(rowData.bio_text_top);
    $('#bio_text_main').val(rowData.bio_text_main);
    $('#bio_text_bot').val(rowData.bio_text_bot);
```

I would like to update the process so that I could call a function to populate the form rather than have to maintain 50+ modules. The call would be

```
    load_Form( prefix, rowData );
```

and the function would be

```
    function load_Form( prefix, rowData ) {
        $('[id^=' + prefix + '_]').each( function() {
            //  What goes here?
        });
    }
```

But I'm at a loss as to what would go in the .each( function() {. I would think something like

```
    $(this).val(rowData.this);
```

But I don't think the 2nd 'this' is correct. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

TIA
James A Wilson
[www.txfannin.org](http://www.txfannin.org)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not as familiar with jQuery, but I imagine the `.each` function takes arguments representing the current item.

Check out the documentation for .each to see the arguments it accepts

Here is an implementation in vanilla js. Note the `element` portion in the `.forEach`

We can then get the id of the element that we matched, and remove the prefix to get the property to match on our data source.

```js
const dataSource = {
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  age: 45,
};

function populateForm(prefix, data) {
  [...document.querySelectorAll(`[id^=${prefix}`)].forEach((element, index, array) => {
    const field = element.getAttribute('id').replace(prefix, '');
    element.value= data[field];
  })
}

populateForm('bio_', dataSource);
```

```html
<input id="bio_firstName"/>
<input id="bio_lastName"/>
<input id="bio_age"/>
```

Comment: I tried your function as follows...

Comment: I tried your function as follows...
```
function populate_Form( prefix, data ) {
 [...document.querySelectorAll(`[id^=${prefix}_`)].forEach((element) => {
  const field = element.getAttribute('id');
  console.log('Field:   ' + field);
  element.innerText = data[field];
  console.log('Element: ' + element.innerText);
 })
}
```
The Field/Element show on the console.log but don't populate the form. The 'textarea' fields show the text but the 'text' fields do no. I removed replace since prefix is part of the Id. Something is missing as the innerText must go into value part of the input.

Comment: @JamesAWilson if target elements are inputs, instead of `innerText` use `.value`. I've updated the answer accordingly